# Questions about ERC-20 tokens

Tags: smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

I know what they are but I don't quite understand the raw fundamentals of how they're expressed, recorded, and sent on the blockchain.

If tokens are just smart contracts, then how do you send them exactly? How do those token transactions get recorded on the blockchain? What are the raw fundamentals of how a token is created from a smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Token balance of an address is recorded on the token contract. A token contract is considered a contract that meets all criteria required by the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard, such as implementing the specified interface and emitting events when required by the standard.

Balances are mostly stored in the form of a [mapping](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html#mapping-types) where the key is the holder address, and the value is the amount of tokens they own, because it's convenient for most cases. However the standard does not specify and particular way so if it suits your needs, you can store the balances in an array, or any other way.

Token transfer is an interaction with the token contract `transfer()` function (standardized in ERC-20), which should perform validations (my example skips that for simplicity), update the local variables storing balances, and emit the (again standardized) `Transfer` event.

Offchain apps, such as Etherscan, can listen to these events and update their own database of token holders. This allows them to filter all tokens by an address in their own database and show them on the website. But again, this is not part of the blockchain data, it's an aggregated database built on top of blockchain.

**Example:** Address `0x123` owns 1 USDT and 2 DAI. The USDT balance is stored in the USDT contract, and the DAI balance is stored in the DAI contract. There's no global property of the `0x123` address keeping track of its tokens.

```
contract USDT {
    // for the key `0x123`, the value is 1 (and decimals)
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public {
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[to] += amount;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount);
    }
}
```

```
contract DAI {
    // for the key `0x123`, the value is 2 (and decimals)
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
}
```

For a full code example, see the OpenZeppelin [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol), and their [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20) related to this specific implementation. Just to clarify, OpenZeppelin is an organization that publishes open source code, but you can also build your own implementation of the standard or use another one, if that fits your use case.

Comment: Well, what about smart contract code, like for example someone can run a program via smart contracts. How does that smart contract connect to the blockchain? How is that code stored, on the blockchain in the payload section?

Comment: @user404 The code is compiled into binary bytecode and then deployed to each node of the network, where it's stored within the [virtual machine](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/) storage. Which makes it inherently "connected" to the blockchain... To be able to run all operations in a deterministic way, you cannot execute other programs (except for other smart contracts of the same network) from within a smart contract.

Comment: Is the code stored in the contract on the blockchain, which gets executed by the virtual machine? I think of the machine as kind of an interpreter of the blockchain, tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user404 You're correct about the interpreter. Btw in terms of processing the bytecode, it's similar to the Java VM or .NET VM, if that helps to understand how EVM works... The source code is not stored anywhere on the blockchain, just the compiled (binary) bytecode. If you want to publish your source code, a common scenario is to publish it to Etherscan (to their own database of source codes, it's not part of the blockchain), but it's not mandatory.

Comment: So the compiled code is stored on the blockchain, but not the source code?

Comment: @user404 That's correct.